# Getting Git error frequently in jenkins jobs

Tags: git, jenkins

My Jenkins job gets failed due to some some Git error, this happens frequently but not everytime.
how to resolve this?

```
22:17:00 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
22:17:00 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@bcds01.de.bosch.com:7999/bse/bse_application.git
22:17:00    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
22:17:00    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1066)
22:17:00    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
22:17:00    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM.checkout(MultiSCM.java:143)
22:17:00    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
22:17:00    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
22:17:00    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
22:17:00 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe reset --hard" returned status code 128:
22:17:00 stdout: 
22:17:00 stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'Sensor/test/system/tools/leshan-server-demo/leshan-server-demo.jar' (Invalid argument)
22:17:00 fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting this error, make sure your commit parent is the HEAD of the branch you push to, i.e Rebase before you push.